# atollic - newlib - stack corruption

Tags: newlib

i use the newlib (standart, not newlib nano) that comes within atollic 8.1.

currently all kinds of XXXprintf versions corrupt my stack and i cant see why.

i have added 3 images to display the problem:

**use case 1**

in image 3.png, you see either vsprintf (rt_vsnprintf ist just a macro forward delaring it) that writes max. 1024 to "sBuf.printf_buffer" which is 1024 bytes long and located at 0x20001c08 (to 0x20002008).

by doing so, the newlib printf functions overwrite at least 1 variable of mine located at 0x20006014, so its not just a overflow by a bit, its quite off....

i tested with sprintf, snprintf, vsnprintf, vsprintf. all those functions write in my variable.

has someone an idea how such behavior could occur?

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/byPERU%20https://ibb.co/dAMuRU%20https://ibb.co/hKtxfp)

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/dAMuRU)

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/byPERU)

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/hKtxfp)

Answer (score 0):

The printf-functions require quite a bit of stack space. How big is your stack, and where is it located? Is it close to your canary variable at address 0x20006014? Could you try making the stack 2 kB bigger and see if there's a difference?